# Gradle build successfully but Getting Runtime Error Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, overlay, android-toolbar

> Error:Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Could not create service of type AnnotationProcessorDetector using JavaGradleScopeServices.createAnnotationProcessorDetector().

I'm getting the above error, I tried alot of things (Set jdk path,add support-annotation library e.t.c)to remove this error but nothing changed. I'm using Android Studio 3.0.1 and toolbar inside my app,minSdk 15 ,maxSdk 26.

This is my gradle:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 0):

There would be sure some error with this, try to **toggle gradle view**. See below image. **You will find error.**.

Also click on red titled line in this view, it will tell you error.

[image]